# PHP force page to have header 200 status instead of 500 error

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script that uses a third party API that requests information using OAuth and then outputs JSON and then I parse the JSON and foreach JSON tree response insert the data into a database, pretty simple, works great but sometimes the API handshake fails for various reasons and gives me a 500 internal error in the console.

The 500 error seems to be out of my control as it's accessing a third party. Is there a way to force the php script to give a status of 200 OK?

I have tried various combinations of the following and still cannot get it to stop the random 500 error in the console:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```

Is there away?

Regardless I would assume what I am trying to do is bad practice but for this scenario, when the 500 error comes up it completely halts my script!

Server: 
Apache 2.4.16,
PHP 5.5.28

Comment: What's the point of returning `200 OK` if you don't return any useful information? And the `500 Internal Error` is not halting your script! It's the other way around: the server returns `500` because your script terminates abnormally.

Comment: fix the disease not the symptom, find and stop the 500-errors

Comment: Looks like this is the error in the apache error log:     error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Answer (score 0):

What your server replies is entirely in your control. If you get a 500 error it's because your code isn't handling the failure, you probably have an exception being raised somewhere.

Check your error log and figure out where the issue is occurring, then handle the error condition and return what you would like.

Comment: So I should tail the error log, see what the exception is and then create a script that says "if error equals this error return header 200"? or is there a way to return header 200 regardless of the exception?

Comment: @ChadPriddle Yeah, just find the source of your issue and handle it. The alternative is to globally set a `set_exception_handler` or you could override  the response in apache (I'm assuming, I don't use it.) or nginx, but both of those options are really terrible practice because your ignoring issues with your actual code that will have unintended consequences. I would highly recommend having error logging and reporting through something like http://getsentry.com, it'll give you a much nicer view with stack trace context over normal logs and will alert you to issues.